# Limit response for each sku

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called purchases and want to get purchases for each sku but only last 2 purchases for each sku.
How can I do that?

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=785e0e2a9c6c27fdfe6c1401a0fd8bf6)

my purchase table sql:

```
CREATE TABLE purchase
(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
sku TEXT NOT NULL,
date DATE NOT NULL
)
```

my desired response:

[image]

Comment: are you looking for last 2 responses based on order of id or order of date?

Comment: @AshishPatil based on the order date. last 2 purchases for each sku

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilise `row_number()`. From your limited sample data it looks like you want the lowest-Id values per SKU, amend the order-by criteria if that's not correct:

```
SELECT id, sku, date 
FROM (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by sku order by date desc) rn
  from purchase
)p
where rn <= 2
order by sku, date;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=93e740b16e920298689959b6790d8413)

Comment: `order by date desc` is the only change I would suggest based on the OP, and perhaps using `with` rather than nesting queries.

Comment: Using a CTE or sub-query is a matter of preference, it makes no difference and ordering by date - yes I somehow saw two rows for the same date, now I focus properly I see they're different, lol.

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```
with p as (
select p.*, row_number() over (partition by sku order by date desc) as rn 
FROM purchase p
)
select * from p where rn <= 2 order by sku,rn
```

[Result here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ca40b9d9bf62385a82cf27a8a1283923)